# which is best for designing forum website - bootstrap or materialize?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, materialized-views

I want to design a forum.
what is best frontend framework between bootstrap and materialize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely go with bootstrap. It´s easy to get started, well documented, supported, responsive, mobile first...

If you want to read more to compare both frameworks I found a good discussion [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/78450)

Also have a look to the [twitter bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) components so you can get familiar with them. It has a lot of features out of the box and there are really good marketplaces out there where you can buy amazing bootstrap templates ready to be used.

Hope it helps!